# I need to export a single WordPress post or page with images and attachments included, and import into a different site

Tags: wordpress, import, export

I need to export a single WordPress post or page with images and attachments included, and import into a different site.

I have tried the standard WordPress Export/Import feature, but it outputs XML with no images or attachments.

The desired result is the page I need to Export/Import, will import to the new site, with all of the content intact, including images and attachments.

The WordPress built in tool will not allow this, and I cannot find a working plugin to do it either.

Comment: I've actually spent a considerable amount of time, reading forum posts, and other resources. Basically the native WordPress feature will not export images, unless you select ALL CONTENT. If you need a subset of your content (e.g., posts filtered by category or date), it simply won't do it. I'm hoping someone has found  workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

An alternate solution that I used - it may sound silly but it does work for me at least:

- use standard Wordpress export function:  export Posts to XML file, then export Media to XML file
- open both XML files in text editor
- copy all the `<item>...</item>`  entries from the posts XML file, into the bottom of the media XML file (before the closing `</channel>` tag), and save that as a new "merged" XML file
- on target site, import this "merged" XML file using standard Wordpress import function  (ensuring you tick the checkbox to import attachments in the process)

Beware, this could take a long time to process, especially if there are a large number of media files to be downloaded from source site and saved to target site - just let it keep processing until it completes.

Comment: Thanks, that helped me a lot.

Answer (score -1):

Try to use this plugin it might help you perform the task you are trying to do, I think this only work between wordpress to wordpress

https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-ultimate-exporter/